# Flutter: Refactor Riverpod provider library into controller and service

Tags: flutter, model-view-controller, riverpod

I am using Riverpod in my app and have the working code below:

```
    @freezed
class LessonDOState with _$LessonDOState {
  const factory LessonDOState(
      {@Default([]) List<LessonDO> lessons,
      @Default({}) Map<int, LessonDO> lessonMap,
      @Default(true) isLoading}) = _LessonDOState;

  const LessonDOState._();
}

final lessonsProvider = StateNotifierProvider<LessonDONotifier, LessonDOState>(
    (ref) => LessonDONotifier());

class LessonDONotifier extends StateNotifier<LessonDOState> {
  LessonDONotifier() : super(const LessonDOState()) {
    loadLessonDOs();
  }

  loadLessonDOs()  async{
    final lessonsData = await rootBundle.rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/lessons.json');
      // Convert list to list of lessons using the movie class constructor
      final lessons = lessonsList.map((e) => LessonDO.fromJson(e)).toList();
      final lessonMap = listToMap(lessons);
      final isLoading = lessons.isEmpty;
      // Update state in provider
      state = state.copyWith(
          lessons: lessons, lessonMap: lessonMap, isLoading: isLoading);
    
  }

  Map<int, LessonDO> listToMap(List<LessonDO> lessons) {
    Map<int, LessonDO> map = {};
    for (LessonDO lesson in lessons) {
      map[lesson.number!] = lesson;
    }
    return map;
  }
}
```

I have read this [article](https://itnext.io/mvc-s-design-pattern-in-flutter-6eba15169413) and want to refactor the above code into `controller` and `service`. Something similar to the below (was taken from [here](https://github.com/SncOne/mvcs-example/tree/main)):

user_provider.dart (controller)

```
    final usersProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<UserNotifier, AsyncValue<List<User>>>(
        (ref) {
  return UserNotifier(ref);
});

class UserNotifier extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<List<User>>> {
  final AutoDisposeStateNotifierProviderRef _ref;
  late final UserService _userService;

  UserNotifier(this._ref) : super(const AsyncValue.data(<User>[])) {
    _userService = _ref.watch(userService);
  }

  Future<void> getUsers() async {
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    final res =
        await AsyncValue.guard(() async => await _userService.getUser());
    state = AsyncValue.data(res.asData!.value);
  }
}
```

user_service.dart (service)

```
    final userService = Provider((ref) => UserService());

class UserService {
  Future<List<User>> getUser() async {
    try {
      const path = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
      final res = await Dio().get(path);
      final List list = res.data;
      return list.map((e) => User.fromJson(e)).toList();
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that I do not understand Riverpod well enough to do that. Please, help.

Comment: New riverpod code should avoid StateNotifier, ChangeNotifier, and StateProvider.  These are deprecated and supported only for backward compatibility.

Comment: Both StateNotifier and StateProvider are present on https://riverpod.dev homepage. Do you say that it is outdated?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz In this article https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-state-management-riverpod/ author says that StateProvider is legacy, but then says using of ChangeNotifier is discouraged and  StateProvider should be used instead. Confusing. What I got so far, is that there are two useful providers StateNotifierProvider and FutureProvider. Actually, to answer my question, I should replace first with last.

Comment: The literature is rushing to catch up to Remi's prolific output.  In brief: generators and the things they generate are preferred.  StateProvider, StateNotifier[Provider], and ChangeNotifier[Provider] are all legacy and should be avoided in new code.